# Sending object through stream

Tags: java, stream

I created a class named Product, with 3 fields (Long)Code, (String)Name, (Double)Price each with its own getter and setter. The created object will be passed to the client that send the matching Code(Long) to the server. My problem here is that I don't know how to build a server and client that can send and receive using Object Stream.

Comment: You can also serialize to json using google's gson and send that over your socket

Comment: Attempt as two problems. How do you serialise objects. Then considering sending across socket. Both problems are solved in many ways.  So your question is too broad to answer.